# Log out all customers from Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, logout, prestashop-1.7

I need a way to log out all signed in customers from my Prestashop site, as a domain name migration caused some issues with user sessions, and having customers sign out and re-sign in is fixing it.

I tried the following code, to no avail:

```
$customers = Customer::getCustomers();
foreach($customers as $customer) {
    $obj = new Customer($customer['id_customer']);
    $obj->logout();
}
```

Is there a way to natively invalidate/destroy all user sessions from Prestashop (code or back office)? Otherwise, plain PHP methods are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the Prestashop cookie to avoid validating login.

It's impossible to change the "cookey-key" because of failing all passwords but you can override Cookie class and change cookie pattern.

Comment: Yes, overriding the Cookie.php class was the way to go, thank you! I added more details in my answer for those interested.

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up going for is pretty much what Mahdi Shad mentioned in his answer, but allow me to add more details:

I changed the prefix of Prestashop cookie names from "Prestashop-" to "MySiteName-" (you can change to whatever you want), by going to `/classes/Cookie.php`, and changing the following line (line 78):

```
$this->_name = 'MySiteName-'.md5(($this->_standalone ? '' : _PS_VERSION_).$name.$this->_domain);
```

**Well, overriding the class instead of directly modifying it is surely a better practice though.**

This change in cookie name immediately makes the old browser cookies obsolete (even if thet aren't expired), and thus all users get signed out. Exactly what I want!